# Mocking Google GeoAPI DistanceMatrix fails with NullPointerException: Mokito 3.6.0, Powermock 2.0.9, JUnit5, SpringBoot 2.3.5 Failing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

## Dependencies Setup

```
dependencies {
    // Testing Frameworks
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }

    // Mockito
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-core:3.6.0')
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.6.0')
    testImplementation('org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.9')

}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
  ignoreFailures = false
  maxParallelForks = 1
  testLogging {
     showStandardStreams = true
     events("skipped", "failed")
  }
}
```

## Subject to Mock

- The Google Geo API for distance matrix (external API call)

```java
...
...  
  /**
   * The API is very expensive to be built
   */
  private GeoApiContext geoApi;

    // Inside of a Google Guave Cache load method...

          // The calculation from Google
    DistanceMatrix calculationResult;
      DistanceMatrixApiRequest req = DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(geoApi);

      calculationResult = req.origins(addresses.getOriginAddress())
            .destinations(addresses.getDestinationAddress())
            .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
            .avoid(RouteRestriction.TOLLS)
            .language(properties.getLanguage())
            .await();
```

## Test Class with Mokito and Powermock

- Then the Test Class is failing... `DistanceMatrixService` is where the call is...
- Tried to implement this in Mokito 3 similar to [How can I mock Google's Geocoding API request using mockito/powermock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641902/how-can-i-mock-googles-geocoding-api-request-using-mockito-powermock)

```java
package ...service.distancematrix;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertSame;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mockStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import com.google.maps.DirectionsApi.RouteRestriction;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApi;
import com.google.maps.DistanceMatrixApiRequest;
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.GeocodingApi;
import com.google.maps.model.Distance;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrix;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrixElement;
import com.google.maps.model.DistanceMatrixRow;
import com.google.maps.model.Duration;
import com.google.maps.model.TravelMode;
import ....distancematrix.model.DistanceMatrixAddresses;
import ....service.distancematrix.model.DistanceMatrixResult;

//@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest({GeocodingApi.class, GeocodingApiRequest.class})
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834940/springboot-cant-resolve-runwith-cannot-find-symbol/63835256#63835256
// https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-junit-5-extension
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@PrepareForTest({GeocodingApi.class, DistanceMatrixApiRequest.class})
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"service.distancematrix.googleMapsApiToken=fake-token"})
@DisplayName("Distance Matrix Service Tests")
public class DistanceMatrixServiceTests {

  private static final String ORIGIN = "Maceio, Alagoas, Brazil";
  private static final String DESTINATION = "Recife, Pernambuco, Brazil";

  @Autowired
  private DistanceMatrixProperties properties;

  @Mock
  private GeoApiContext geoApiContext;


  @InjectMocks
  private DistanceMatrixService service;

  @Test
  public void testGetDistanceMatrixForAddresses() throws Exception {
    DistanceMatrixAddresses addresses = new DistanceMatrixAddresses();
    addresses.setDestinationAddress(DESTINATION);
    addresses.setOriginAddress(ORIGIN);

    DistanceMatrixElement element = new DistanceMatrixElement();
    element.distance = new Distance();
    element.distance.inMeters = 300L;
    element.duration = new Duration();
    element.duration.inSeconds = 44L;

    DistanceMatrixRow row = new DistanceMatrixRow();
    row.elements = new DistanceMatrixElement[] {element};

    DistanceMatrix distanceMatrixResult = new DistanceMatrix(
        new String[] {ORIGIN}, new String[]{DESTINATION}, new DistanceMatrixRow[]{row});

    DistanceMatrixApiRequest distanceMatrixRequest = PowerMockito.mock(DistanceMatrixApiRequest.class);
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.origins(ORIGIN)).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.destinations(DESTINATION)).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.avoid(RouteRestriction.TOLLS)).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.language(properties.getLanguage())).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);

    // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION IS RIGHT IN THE await()'s internal method on base class
    when(distanceMatrixRequest.await()).thenReturn(distanceMatrixResult);

    mockStatic(GeocodingApi.class);

    when(DistanceMatrixApi.newRequest(eq(geoApiContext))).thenReturn(distanceMatrixRequest);

    DistanceMatrixResult calculatedResult = service.getDriveDistance(addresses);

    assertSame(distanceMatrixResult, calculatedResult);
  }

}
```

## Stacktrace with Failure details

- The test fails with a NullPointerException...
- `distancematrix.DistanceMatrixServiceTests.testGetDistanceMatrixForAddresses(DistanceMatrixServiceTests.java:87)` is exactly the `await()` method call... But it has been mocked with `when`
  `when(distanceMatrixRequest.await()).thenReturn(distanceMatrixResult);`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.maps.PendingResultBase.makeRequest(PendingResultBase.java:80)
    at com.google.maps.PendingResultBase.await(PendingResultBase.java:57)
    at ...distancematrix.DistanceMatrixServiceTests.testGetDistanceMatrixForAddresses(DistanceMatrixServiceTests.java:87)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

## Questions

- Is the ExtendsWith correct? Why's the mock null?
- Should I be using anything else?